# Synchronising SFML with C++ Project on GitHub

Tags: c++, visual-c++, github, sfml

At the moment I'm using Visual Studio C++ with SFML Graphics, Windows, and System libraries (plus opengl / relevant dependencies).

I'm attempting to sync this project with a group of us who all need to work on it (via GitHub) but it seems (at first glance, at least) like the project file will need different 'include' paths for each person wanting to run the project on their machine. Could get tedious if we're all constantly syncing different settings.

*TL;DR*: Is there a way to install SFML to the project directory so that the project can be opened and run on any machine without needing to configure the project settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a variant, I'm storing only source in the repository, without project preferences. It also helps in different platforms. I use windows+visual stuido and linux+eclipse. 
Or you really can put "include", "lib" folders of SFML into your projects directory like other usual files.